# SQL - How to select rows which have the same multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'll start with a simplified example of my table:

```
+-----+----------+
|Name |Teaches   |
+-----+----------+  
|Dave |Science   |
+-----+----------+  
|Dave |History   |
+-----+----------+  
|Alice|History   |
+-----+----------+  
|Alice|Literature|
+-----+----------+  
|Alice|Science   |
+-----+----------+  
|John |History   |
+-----+----------+
```

I'm trying to select those people who also teach the same classes as Dave. (In this case, Alice). I'm thinking of using a cursor to go through Dave's courses and selecting those people who teach the same course and intersecting the results, but I'd like to know if there is a better (simpler) way.

Comment: Self join should work. quick and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.name
from t join
     t td
     on td.teaches = t.teaches 
where td.name = 'Dave'
group by t.name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.name = 'Dave');
```

Comment: this has a lot of aggregations?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala . . . "Dave" teaches all the classes that Dave teaches:  "I'm trying to select those people who also teach the same classes as Dave".  The OP, of course, can filter out Dave if s/he so chooses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Self join`, something like this

```
SELECT a.NAME
FROM   Table1 a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Teaches,
                          Count(*)OVER() AS cnt
                   FROM   Table1
                   WHERE  NAME = 'Dave') b
               ON a.Teaches = b.Teaches
WHERE  a.NAME <> 'Dave'
GROUP  BY a.NAME,
          b.cnt
HAVING Count(*) = b.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

One method, used `CTE` here.

```
;WITH CTE_Parent
AS  (
    SELECT  Name,Teaches,COUNT(*) OVER() AS Parent_Count
    FROM    @Teachers
    WHERE   Name    =   'Dave'
)

SELECT  T.Name
FROM    @Teachers   AS  T
    INNER JOIN  CTE_Parent  AS  C   ON  C.Name  <>  T.Name
                                    AND C.Teaches=  T.Teaches
GROUP BY T.Name,C.Parent_Count
HAVING  COUNT(*)    =   C.Parent_Count
```